# Import Magento db into local dev server: MySQL Error 1215

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I'd like to work locally on a Magento development website, rather than on a remote production website.

When I import the exported SQL, I keep running into `MySQL Error 1215`.

[This Q&A](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31702/mysql-error-while-importing-database) suggests:

> 1) Open the exported sql file of your database and add following sql
>   query at the begining
>
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
>
> 2) Goto the end of the file and add
>
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

This allowed me to import the `.SQL` without running into errors.

Is it a wise move to use this workaround?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t tell us exactly what’s wrong but at least the 1215 error tells me that the foreign key is the problem.

If you ever want to find out, why that error was , all you have to do is run below command and look for "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR":

```
mysql> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

That will narrow it down a bit. It’s either a non-indexed parent key, or a data type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

I do this import almost daily and never have had any issues with Foreign Key Checks since I started doing the following steps.

1. Do your dump with `mysqldump` from the command line on the source machine.
2. Start with an empty database, drop the database and recreate it to ensure this before importing your database dump.

mysqldump is intelligent enough to dump data out of a database in the proper order and include all the commands to import the data so that it doesn't run into foreign key issues during the import.

What causes issues is that unless you start with an empty database, tables exist in the database and despite having drop table commands in the database import, there's always a number of tables in existence that have foreign key constraints. Start clean or you have to set foreign key constraints off and hope the data came in cleanly.

NOTE: If a clean commandline mysql dump will not import into an empty database without error, you need to start thinking about running the Magento database repair tool to deal with database corruption that hasn't caused your website to crash yet.